# How can i connect a timer to a label

Tags: c#, timer, label

I'm developing a maze game at beginner level on C# and what i want to do is create a timer that shows up on the top right corner of the game. The timer is supposed to count down from 1000 (999, 998, 997 every second etc). I wouldn't know how to connect a label that displays the timer that i want to create. How would i go about it? I wouldn't know how to begin on the Tick-method.

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

}
```

Hope i made myself somewhat clear.

Comment: Write code to add text to the label based on a var you decrement?

Comment: @Plutonix How would i go about that? That's what i'm wondering.

Comment: Research and trying to implement some of what you learn will likely be more fruitful than *wondering*

Comment: @Plutonix Obviously i've tried different things but neither have worked. Isn't this site about asking questions and learning? But thank you for being very helpful.

Comment: No, it is *not* obvious either from the lack of code and garbled title.

Comment: @Plutonix Didn't think that was worth mentioning since i was hardly even close. As far as the title i'm sure i could do it better but hopefully i explained myself in the rest of the post. Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private int _count = 1000
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _count--;
    myLabel.Text = _count.ToString();
}
```

The assumption is you have a label on your form, and you have started your timmer

Comment: That looks correct, thank you. I was also able to adjust the Interval property of the timer to fit what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You also may want to add `if (_count == 0) timer2.Stop();`

Comment: This is a very basic approach. The timer event may be skipped when UI thread is busy and you may end up with significantly longer time than expected 1000 sec.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek, Im guessing he is not building halo 12.x, however im with you, there are more suitable approaches once he figures out labels :))

Comment: @RufusL Yes that is a relevant function to the game, thank you!